# Is this method asynchronous?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, httpclient, response

This method uses `.Result`. Does that mean the tasks will not run asynchronously? Does it require refactoring to enable each request for a token to be truly async?

```
public async Task<string> ReturnDataFromUrlAsync(List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> listOfPostData)
{
    string allTokens = "";

    var client = new HttpClient
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:23081")
    };

    var downloadTasksQuery = listOfPostData.Select(postData =>
    {
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("/Token", content).Result;                                 
        var responseBodyAsText = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return responseBodyAsText;               
    });

    List<Task<string>> downloadTasks = downloadTasksQuery.ToList();   

    while (downloadTasks.Count > 0)
    {
        Task<string> firstFinishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(downloadTasks);

        downloadTasks.Remove(firstFinishedTask);

        // Await the completed task. 
        string content = await firstFinishedTask;

        allTokens = allTokens + content;
    }

    return allTokens;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So at the moment this call:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("/Token", content).Result;
```

Will cause the calling thread to stall and wait for the result. If you place the await key word before `client.PostAsync` it will cause the calling thread to return to the caller and resume once the operation has completed. As this is being done in a  linq query you will need to make the lambda expression asynchronous like so:

```
var downloadTasksQuery = listOfPostData.Select(async postData =>
    {
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("/Token", content);                               
        var responseBodyAsText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return responseBodyAsText;               
    });
```

Appending the async keyword in a lambda expression will infer that the return type must be of type Task, and as we are are also selecting strings it will of type `IEnumerable<Task<string>>`

I also noticed this:

```
var responseBodyAsText = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I think the reason for the confusion is because this statement is actually returning a Task not a string (be careful what you name stuff if you are using `var`)

Once again we can just place the await keyword before the `response.Content` and the return key will be inferred automatically. Then we can select strings, in the linq query rather than `Task<string>`

Comment: Hi @William how do I change response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); so that it returns a Task<string>? For example, Task<string> responseBodyAsText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); does not work.

Comment: Yeah it won't work because `await` unpacks the result of `ReadAsStringAsync()` so really you want `string responseBodyAsText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` Without the await keyword in there it would return `Task<string>`

Comment: No matter what I do if I don't use .Result no data is returned! Your tips are great ta, but at the moment I still cannot remove the .Result

Comment: Have you placed the await keyword before the client.PostAsync?. This is automaticly getting the result from the method

Comment: Yes. But I have to remove await and re add .Result to get data

Comment: In debug, with await, the code flow quits at this point. The await keyword appears to throw an exception

Comment: It's important to note that `.Result` and `await` perform the same action in that they unbox the result of the operation. The only difference being calling `Result` will stall the calling thread, which is normally the UI thread, while await will cause this thread to bubble back up where it was called, which is normally an event handler

Comment: Where is `ReturnDataFromUrlAsync` called from? Is something else depending on the result of this operation?

Comment: This is calling method:  Task<String> response = ReturnDataFromUrlAsync(listOfPostData);
                       var result = response.Result;
                       claims.Add(new Claim("token", result));

Comment: So there is no problem in the calling method. What's the exception + inner exception?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96448/discussion-between-william-and-steve).